# Which is the Gomanta mountain, to which Krishna & Balaram fled?

Tags: krishna, parashurama, harivamsa, geography

**[Chapter 39 of Vishnu Parva of Harivamsa](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_039.html)** gives a conversation between Lord Parshurama and Shri Krishna where he is telling them about the Gomanta mountain:

> tatashchyutA gamiShyAmaH sahyasya vivare girim |
>   gomantamiti vikhyAtaM naikashR^i~NgavibhUShitam ||2-39-64

Leaving this place let us go to the mountain, located in the gap of sahya, famous as gomantam, decorated with a beautiful peak.

> sopAnabhUtaM svargasya gaganAdrimivochChritam |
>   taM vimAnAvataraNaM giriM merumivAparam ||2-39-66

Like the steps of heaven, high like a mountain in the sky, **that mountain like meru, is a landing place for aerial vehicles.**

> UrmimantaM samudraM cha apAradvIpabhUShaNam |
>   prekShamANau sukhaM tatra nagAgre vichariShyathaH ||2-39-68

Watching the sea, full of waves and decorated with many islands, you can wander on the peak of the mountain comfortably.

Wikipedia says that Gomanta kingdom corresponds to the modern state of Goa and from the description it seems likely but my question is - **Which mountain in this region corresponds to the mountain described by Parashurama which served as the landing base of Vimanas?**

Answer (score 1):

Its identity is disputed.  Here is what page 52 of [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=NhVWAAAAYAAJ&dq=gomanta+sahya&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ4Oe1y43YAhVEOo8KHSSYCV8Q6AEIOjAE) says:

> Pargiter identifies it with the hill of Gwalior, which, according to Cunningham, was originally called Gopacala, Gopagiri and Gopahvaya, and later Gomanta. But as according to the Harivamsa (Visnuparva, 39, 62-64) it lay to the south of the town of Vanavasi, it is more reasonable to place it in the Mysore region as suggested by Raychaudhuri. And Chardragutti in the Shimaga district of the Mysore State was actually known as Gomanta-parvata. It is, thus, a part of the Sahya range.

Comment: Hmmm how did Goa fit in then? Even now Goans identify with the term Gomanta most. There is also a newspaper in Goa with that name - http://epaper.dainikgomantak.com/flashclient/client_panel.aspx

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Well, it's possible that there's multiple places with the name Gomanta.

Comment: Ya but I want to know the most likely location. Why would Krishna and Balaram go as far as Goa or Mysore while fleeing from Mathura/Vrindavan?